# Is the tangent bundle of hyperbolic space trivial?

Tags: manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $H$ be hyperbolic 3-space. Let $TH$ be the tangent bundle of $H$. I have a question:

Is $TH$ isometric to H times a flat $k$-space?

Comment: What metric are you putting on the total space of the tangent bundle? (Also, this is not the usual meaning of "trivial." With the usual meaning of trivial, which doesn't involve metrics, the answer is yes.)

Comment: Natural metrics on the tangent bundle and the computation of their curvature are discussed in http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/students/Elias-Kappos-MSc.pdf